# How do I read multiple lines from STDIN into a variable?

Tags: bash, scripting

I've been googling this question to no avail. I'm automating a build process here at work, and all I'm trying to do is get version numbers and a tiny description of the build which may be multi-line. The system this runs on is OSX 10.6.8.

I've seen everything from using CAT to processing each line as necessary. I can't figure out what I should use and why.

#### Attempts

```
read -d '' versionNotes
```

Results in garbled input if the user has to use the backspace key. Also there's no good way to terminate the input as ^D doesn't terminate and ^C just exits the process.

```
read -d 'END' versionNotes
```

Works... but still garbles the input if the backspace key is needed.

```
while read versionNotes
do
  echo "  $versionNotes" >> "source/application.yml"
done
```

Doesn't properly end the input (because I'm too late to look up matching against an empty string).

Comment: You're getting this information from the user, correct?

Comment: Correct; I want the user to enter this information in the terminal when executing the script.

Comment: You haven't made yourself clear, I'd rather say.

Answer (score 36):

`man bash` mentions «…

> The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).

…»

```
$ myVar=$(</dev/stdin)
hello
this is test
$ echo $myVar
hello this is test
$ echo "$myVar"
hello
this is test
```

and I agree this is worth mentioning — `echo "$myVar"` would have displayed the input as it was given.

Comment: How to stop after multiline input? If I press Ctrl C it stops but the variable is not saved!

Comment: UNIX® terminals do have "discipline": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline

• Check it out what does "eof" mean
• Do read `man stty`, find out how to get current settings

Comment: ctrl-d to stop.

Comment: A complement from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42866846/1879269), if you want to write directly into a file, simply use ```echo "$(</dev/stdin)" > /tmp/file```.

Answer (score 24):

**Try this:**

```
user@host:~$ read -d '' x <<EOF
> mic
> check
> one
> two
> EOF
```

***Without* line breaks:**

```
user@host:~$ echo $x
mic check one two
```

***With* line breaks:**

```
user@host:~$ echo "$x"
mic
check
one
two
```

Comment: `-d ''` is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @Bruno My pleasure; it's a tricky one. Especially at first glance, it looks fairly standard. Can be quite useful though, once you get the hang of the various idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 9):

Refer to the excellent [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for all your bash scripting needs.

In particular the Bash FAQ contains this at number #1:

[**How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: You say to use `read -r`, but how do I get it to do so from STDIN? I did attempt to use `read -r` early on.

Comment: It reads from stdin by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can start an editor like vim, pico...

```
${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}} source/application.yml
```

Comment: Um... how does that answer the OP's question in any way ?

Comment: He can start the editor from the script.

Comment: And that accomplishes what, exactly ? He wants to use text *from* a file in the script, not write information *to* a file.

Comment: He wasnts to read text from the user and write it to a file. Please read the comments added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue by dealing with each line until I came up with a blank line. It works well enough for my situation. But if someone wants to add a better solution, feel free to do so.

```
echo "---
notes: |" > 'version.yml'

while read line
do
  # break if the line is empty
  [ -z "$line" ] && break
  echo "  $line" >> "source/application.yml"
done
```

Comment: Use `read -r` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First a few corrections:

1. To allow "edition" on the line use `-e` which uses readline (so you have the bash history and all editing features)
2. `-d` only takes one character. E.g. from 'END' takes 'E' and whenever the user writes an 'E' the reading stops (I guess that's not what you want...)

There are a few possibilities to do this. I'd go for read line by line and stop when an empty line is found (though you could set any stop word):

```
unset tmp
while :
do 
 read line
 [[ $line == "" ]] && tmp="${tmp:0:$((${#tmp}-1))}" && break
 tmp="$tmp"$line$'\n'
done
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using a construct using xargs and ctrl-d for breaking.  I'm not perfectly satisfied with it, but it certainly does the job of taking multi-line user input and stuffing that into a variable (formatting intact).  (The first and third assignments add quotes around the contents of the xargs input.)

```
    printf '%s\n' "When finished hit ctrl-d on a new line to proceed.  " "" "" 
    # this will load the user's input into a variable instead of a file 
    reminderBody="\"" 
    reminderBody+=$( xargs -0 ) 
    reminderBody+="\""
```

We use reminderBody as the body of an e-mail being sent by mail (via bash).

Answer (score 1):

As in your comment you are stating that the input comes from a user via terminal: You can use `read` to read multi line input via

```
read -d $'\04' versionNotes
```

which sets the delimiter to EOF, which is `0x04` in unicode so you can read input until `CTRL-D` is given.

Answer (score 0):

You have several methods.

One of the simplest methods is:

```
MYVAR=$(yourcommand)
echo $"MYVAR"
```

For example:

```
MYVAR=$(ls /)
echo $"MYVAR"
```

Comment: Except I'm not executing a shell command like LS. I'm requesting multi-line input from the user.

Comment: This is very bad practice; do not process the output of `ls`!

Comment: @adaptr We've heard it all before, would you mind suggesting a good alternative, please?

Answer (score -1):

See: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#READR

Use `read` and note that if you end a line with `\` the newline is ignored.  So you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "version: " version
echo $version

# enter some input and end long lines with "\", then plain enter at the end
read -p "description: " description
echo -e "$version\n$description >> yourfile.txt
```

Comment: If I just wanted a paragraph with line breaks ignored, yes. But as this is a generated list of release notes for a build script, I need to be able to preserve those line breaks; I might try to enter a bulleted list, for example.

Comment: The ABS is a monstrosity of horrific proportions. 90% of it is plain wrong.

Comment: It's not *that* bad.